# Deploy on premise data gateway on Azure VM via ARM

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

We have successfully configured a On Premise data gateway on an Azure VM, using this gateway as trigger in a logic app works. All this is done manually.

Is there a way to achieve this with ARM? Is there a sample ARM template available for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create on-premise data gateway with ARM template. Please have a try to use the following ARM template, it works correctly on my side.

Deploy.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "gatewayApiVersion": {
        "type": "String"
      },
        "gatewayName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gatewayLocation": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "gatewayInstallationId": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connectionGateways",
            "name": "[parameters('gatewayName')]",
            "apiVersion": "[parameters('gatewayApiVersion')]",
            "location": "[parameters('gatewayLocation')]",
            "properties": {
                "connectionGatewayInstallation": {
                    "Id": "[parameters('gatewayInstallationId')]"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Parameters.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "gatewayApiVersion": {
      "value": "2015-08-01-preview"
    },
    "gatewayName": {
      "value": "gatewayName"
    },
    "gatewayLocation": {
      "value": "location"
    },
    "gatewayInstallationId": {
      "value": "/subscriptions/{subscriotionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/{location}/connectionGatewayInstallations/xxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
```

Before that we need to  Install the on-premises data gateway manually on the machine, more details about how install on-premises data gateway please refer to the [azure document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install)

For **gatewayLocation** value, please make sure that the same with on-premises 
data gateway.

[image]

For **gatewayInstallationId** value, if we try to create it from azure we could get value from the portal.

[image]

Test result:

[image]